# midiInGetDevCaps Midi Device Names

Tags: c#, midi

I've used the following code from this link.

[Getting signals from a MIDI port in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991159/getting-signals-from-a-midi-port-in-c/2024835%232024835)

I'm wondering what I need to add to able to get a list of device names.
I've looked the MSDN website and found I need to implement `midiInGetDevCaps` and its a associated struct. But I've never really done anything with dll imports and structs before so I'm a bit lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you need use it like this:

```
MIDIINCAPS caps2;

for (uint i = 0; i < Device.iNumDevs1; i++)
{
    Device.midiOutGetDevCaps(i, out caps2, Marshal.SizeOf(output));
    comboBox2.Items.Add(caps2.szPname);
}
```

Comment: don't forget to mark the answer as correct if it helped you out :)